# How to remove black frame when AVPlayer replaces current AVPlayerItem?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I trying to play videos as Instagram does. Every time the user taps the screen I should play the next one. My problem is that I see a black frame on the player every time I change a video. If the video was recorded with a new phone the black frame takes longer to disappear.

I tried to change the `AVPlayer` each time I change between videos and it works but the player crashes or stops working after 12 or 15 videos.

```
 func startPlayer() {
        configure()
        play()
    }

 func playNext() {  
       guard let dataSource = dataSource else { return }
        if playingIndex < dataSource.numberOfPlayerVideoViewItems() - 1 {
            playItem(playingIndex + 1)
            return
        }
        resetIndex()
        startPlayer()
    }

 fileprivate func configure() {
    guard let playerVideoItem = dataSource?.playerVideoView(self, playerVideoViewItemAt:playingIndex),
        let videoURL = playerVideoItem.itemURL else { return }

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    if player == nil {
        player = AVPlayer.init(url: videoURL)
        player?.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = true;

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    } else {
        player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem.init(url: videoURL))
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(videoDidFinish(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)

    observeProgress(for: player!.currentItem!)
}
```